# Views of UITabBarController behind NavigationBar

Tags: xcode, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I'm actually having problems by designing my app with the storyboard.
My starting view is a UITabBarController. It has different kind of controllers : UIViewControllers and UITableViewControllers.

My TabBarController has a property : UINavigationBar *navBar;
Indeed, I want to display a navigation bar in my app.

My problem is that every subcontrollers has its view displayed with origin below the navigation bar.

I've get round this problem with the ViewController, by adding a first view, and then adding the others views considering the height of the navigation bar.

But the problem persists, and I can't use the same trick with the TableViewController.

So is their something to set in the storyboard, or in the .m file of my TabBarController, so the others controllers are aware that a navigation bar is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You should do you view size calculations always based on the dynamic size of the view. E.g.

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width - 20,
                                     self.view.bounds.size.height- 20);
```

If there is a nav bar or a tab bar, the view will be adjusted automatically and the above will have the expected results.

Besides, it is normally preferable to work with AutoLayout in order to avoid any hard coded sizing.